# How can I stop wicd from starting at boot time?

Tags: 12.04, networking, wicd

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have installed something that starts automatically in full screen when Ubuntu starts, but I have a problem with wicd. wicd always starts first even it is connected to the internet and i have to close it to start the other program. So is there anything to do to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, After closing WICD, go to Unity Menu, and search `Startup Applications, then click on Startup applications.

Then when you find wicd remove it from the list.

Then restart your computer to see if this thing still happens or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart && sudo mv wicd-tray.desktop wicd-tray.desktop.backup
```

should work. XDG stands for X Desktop Group, now called FreeDesktop.org, a creator of standards that desktops such as Unity, Gnome, and KDE adhere to. Startup application control is such a standard: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#idm140060498435024